# Find the earliest common descendants from a complex parent/child table and ignore further descendants

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy

I'm using SQL Server 2019. I have a complex organisational structure where an employee may have multiple managers and a manager may have multiple employees. Plus there are many layers of management involved. As such, we've got a parent/child table to hold all the relationships rather than a hierarchy. From here though, I can use a CTE to traverse the list to see which downstream employees are linked to a particular manager or which upstream managers are linked to an employee.

What I'm struggling with is to find an easy way to identify common employees for managers that may be several, and different, levels up the organisation.

For example (note that the hierarchy path doesn't exist in the database but is generated by a CTE for each example manager):

```
Manager #461
Parent | Child -> Example hierarchy output path
  461  |  400  -> /461/400/
  461  |  401  -> /461/401/
  400  |  336  -> /461/400/336/
  400  |  337  -> /461/400/337/
  400  |  338  -> /461/400/338/
  401  |  336  -> /461/401/336/
  401  |  337  -> /461/401/337/
  401  |  338  -> /461/401/338/
  337  |  500  -> /461/400/337/500
               -> /461/401/337/500
  338  |  500  -> /461/400/338/500
               -> /461/401/338/500

Manager #462
Parent | Child -> Example hierarchy output path
  462  |  337  -> /462/337/
  462  |  338  -> /462/338/
  337  |  500  -> /462/337/500/
  338  |  500  -> /462/338/500/
```

What I would like to do is ask what are the employees linked to both  `461` and `462`. The answers would be `337` and `338` but what I want to exclude is that `500` is also a common employee. I'd like to ultimately come up with a table like:

```
Manager1 |     Path1     | Manager2 |   Path2
   461   | /461/400/337/ |    462   | /462/337/
   461   | /461/401/337/ |    462   | /462/337/
   461   | /461/400/338/ |    462   | /462/338/
   461   | /461/401/338/ |    462   | /462/338/
```

I've tried making a table by joining on the last node ID (`SELECT * FROM output1 JOIN output2 on RIGHT(output1.path,4) = RIGHT(output2.path,4)`) but this also includes the `500` paths. What I'd like to do is somehow *exclude any descendant nodes once an ancestor node is matched*.

Current output (bad):

```
Manager1 |     Path1         | Manager2 |   Path2
   461   | /461/400/337/     |    462   | /462/337/
   461   | /461/401/337/     |    462   | /462/337/
   461   | /461/400/338/     |    462   | /462/338/
   461   | /461/401/338/     |    462   | /462/338/
   461   | /461/400/337/500/ |    462   | /462/337/500/
   461   | /461/401/337/500/ |    462   | /462/337/500/
   461   | /461/400/338/500/ |    462   | /462/338/500/
   461   | /461/401/338/500/ |    462   | /462/338/500/
```

Is there a way to stop the join or delete records from the output table if an ancestor already exists in the output table?

Just to make it more complicated, this is a simple example. There are many layers to the structure and there might be another common descendant that's branched off to the side many levels up or down so just grouping by path length and selecting the shortest path doesn't work. That's why I don't want to look at path length or hierarchy levels as the filter but instead check if a common ancestor exists and if so, stop joining further descendants or remove them from the output.

Thanks